# Upgrade from polymer 0.5 to 0.8

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, polymer, bower

Hello I am trying to upgrade polymerJs from `0.5 to 0.8` using bower. As we know that running `bower update` will update all of the necessary packages.

But unfortunately it is updating to `0.5.5` not to `0.8`. Can someone please let me know what exactly the problem is or how can i achieve the upgrade ? Much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your `bower.json` file should be referencing `Polymer/polymer#^0.8.0-rc.2`.  Most likely it is referencing version 0.5.x.

It should be noted, however, that many of the default components are not yet compatible with 0.8, and a lot of things may break as a result.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that some element haven't ported to 0.8 and it's not backward compatible. You can check ported elements progress here http://chuckh.github.io/road-to-polymer/repos-compare.html?load=true

For start new project with Polymer you can do it with bower like below

```
bower install --save Polymer/polymer#0.8-preview
```